# What is an equi-depth partition of the data?

Tags: dataset, partitioning

In the paper  [Outlier Detection for High Dimensional Data](http://charuaggarwal.net/outl.pdf) at the beginning of section 1.3 Is written:

*Each attribute of the data is
divided into $\phi$ equi-depth ranges. Thus, each range contains
a fraction f = 1 /$\phi$ of the records.*

What does it mean?   Can you write an example?
If the data is $n \times p$ will I get $\phi$  matrix of size $\dfrac{n}{\phi}\times p$?

Comment: It seems to me the second sentence of the quotation includes the answer to the question.

Comment: After a while my understanding is that each variables have to be split  in $\phi$ parts independently from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a matrix where the rows represent entries and columns attributes. An equi-depth split would be a split of phi boxes, where each box would contain some elements with all their attributes.